# What is the best way for all instances of an Ember component to share a variable?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I have an Ember component which is essentially a panel. There can be multiple instances of this panel on a page, but only one can be "active" at any given time. Each instance of the component must be aware if any of the other panels become "active" so they can remove their "active" state. I would really rather not move the JavaScript to make this happen to a parent component. Instead, I would like to keep it within this component. In Angular, I used to use a static variable to do this. What is best way to do this in Ember?

Answer (score 3):

> I would really rather not move the JavaScript to make this happen to a
>   parent component

Do you want to avoid having the parent component dealing with anything related to panel "activity"? If so, why?* If not:

Ember automatically gives each component's tag (unless it's a tagless component) an id that is accessible from the js code as [`elementId`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Component/properties/elementId?anchor=elementId). You could create a property `activePanelId` on the parent component and pass it to all panels: `{{pa-nel activePanelId=activePanelId}}` and then check in each panel

```
{{#if (eq elementId activePanelId)}}
  {{!whatever is different on the active panel}}
{{/if}}
```

or use it in the js code:

```
isActive: Ember.computed('activePanelId', function() {
    return this.get('activePanelId')===this.get('elementId');
},
```

If the panel becomes active by an action related to itself (e.g. clicking on it), just set `activePanelId` to the `elementId` in the respective action - since the property `activePanelId` exists only once on the parent component, all other panels to which it is passed will take note.

If using the `elementId` feels to hacky, you might as well give each panel a distinct name and store the `activePanelName` in the calling component.

*If you really do not want the property in the parent component, you could move it to a service that you then inject into the panel components, but I cannot yet imagine a good reason for preferring that.

Comment: What about using contextual components?  Ember docs - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/#toc_sharing-component-data-with-its-wrapped-content so you could have a panel-header and use the component helper

Comment: @rossjha I never used those (and I am having trouble wrapping my head around them so late in the evening ;-) ). Feel free to write an answer based on it - I would be interested to see how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

@arne.b 's anwser sums it pretty well, the best way of handling component's state with common parent data, but if you are dead serious about not using a parent component there is kind of way to get it done.

Example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
   sharedObject: {},
   sharedArray: [],
});
```

In the above component you can use `sharedObject` or `sharedArray` to exchange state with  multiple instances of the component. Any changes in the object or array will be reflected to all the instances of the same component.

A sample [Ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8a6527aebf829ee1876bccb5e3ee47b1?openFiles=components.my-comp.js%2C).

Comment: This is not a good way of doing things because it mutates the component prototype.

One unintended side effect is that changes to the component prototype will remain across integration tests. This can cause later tests to start with data that you didn't intend and can lead to all kinds of hard to track failures.

A better approach if you don't want to create a parent component is to create a service (which is a singleton by default) and inject it into any components that you want to share state.